# How do you create a file from a string in Gulp?

Tags: node.js, gulp

In my gulpfile I have a version number in a string.  I'd like to write the version number to a file.  Is there a nice way to do this in Gulp, or should I be looking at more general NodeJS APIs?

Comment: Exact requirement.. Around version number... I want to use it to append it to assets url for cache bursting

Answer (score 79, accepted):

If you'd like to do this in a gulp-like way, you can create a stream of "fake" vinyl files and call `pipe` per usual. Here's a function for creating the stream. "stream" is a core module, so you don't need to install anything:

```
const Vinyl = require('vinyl')

function string_src(filename, string) {
  var src = require('stream').Readable({ objectMode: true })
  src._read = function () {
    this.push(new Vinyl({
      cwd: "",
      base: "",
      path: filename,
      contents: Buffer.from(string, 'utf-8')
    }))
    this.push(null)
  }
  return src
}
```

You can use it like this:

```
gulp.task('version', function () {
  var pkg = require('package.json')
  return string_src("version", pkg.version)
    .pipe(gulp.dest('build/'))
})
```

Comment: I ended up doing basically this, but with event-stream's [readArray](https://github.com/dominictarr/event-stream#readarray-array) to create the stream.

Comment: For those who aren't up to speed on streams, you can have this work on multiple files strings by repeating the two lines within `_read` for each file. In this instance, an array of file objects would be a better `sting_src` parameter.

Comment: This covered my use case of creating a stream to pipe with other Gulp plugins down the road.

Comment: If anyone else is as unfamiliar with node as me, node provides `Buffer` as a global (https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html).

Comment: This worked for me but `this.push(null)` throws an error `stream.push() after EOF` for me, not sure why. Commenting out that line works but then gulp hangs indefinitely.

Comment: @Daryl can you please share your code somewhere? I'd like to do this for multiple files but I'm new to pipes in `nodejs`

Comment: This doesn't appear to work any more. Not sure which one of the myriad of dependencies in gulp has caused this to fail though.

Comment: **Note**: `new Buffer()` is [deprecated since v6](https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html#buffer_new_buffer_string_encoding). Use `Buffer.from()` instead.

Answer (score 75):

It's pretty much a one-liner in node:

```
require('fs').writeFileSync('dist/version.txt', '1.2.3');
```

Or from package.json:

```
var pkg = require('./package.json');
var fs = require('fs');
fs.writeFileSync('dist/version.txt', 'Version: ' + pkg.version);
```

---

I'm using it to specify a build date in an easily-accessible file, so I use this code before the usual `return gulp.src(...)` in the `build` task:

```
require('fs').writeFileSync('dist/build-date.txt', new Date());
```

Comment: This is probably the best way to do this (unless you're using ShellJS).

Comment: `writeFile` function is now asynchronous and requires a callback. You might want to use 'writeFileSync' or better being reactive and pass a callback to do something when the file is actually written on disk.

Comment: How does one go about chaining (pipe?) to access the file created from this? Since it's more of a node method, I cannot gain access to the file created within the same build task.

Comment: @beauXjames you can use [mjhasbach's solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30455405/288906) or just add `gulp.src('dist/version.txt').pipe(…)` after the `.writeFileSync` line.

Comment: I just threw this in before one of my tasks and worked like a charm.

Comment: Thanks, it is only way to do on windows machine!

Comment: Loved it. I used this to generate a random string to use as a cache buster.

https://gist.github.com/cmeza/e5488609d09722bd2c82e954859f36cf

Answer (score 28):

This can also be done with [vinyl-source-stream](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vinyl-source-stream). See [this document](https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/blob/master/docs/recipes/make-stream-from-buffer.md) in the gulp repository.

```
var gulp = require('gulp'),
    source = require('vinyl-source-stream');

gulp.task('some-task', function() {
    var stream = source('file.txt');

    stream.end('some data');
    stream.pipe(gulp.dest('output'));
});
```

Comment: This is probably the cleanest node way if you want to use `.pipe()`

Comment: Could you explain the `process.nextTick(fn() { stream.end(); }`?

Comment: @Chic I ended the stream in a `process.nextTick` callback because that is how it was done in the gulp documentation. It does not appear to be necessary, so I updated the answer. Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 27):

According to the maintainer of Gulp, the preferred way to write a string to a file is using [`fs.writeFile`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_writefile_file_data_options_callback) with the task callback.

```
var fs = require('fs');
var gulp = require('gulp');

gulp.task('taskname', function(cb){
  fs.writeFile('filename.txt', 'contents', cb);
});
```

Source: https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/issues/332#issuecomment-36970935

Comment: Only problem with this is it requires the file to exist... isn't there a flag that allows this file to be created if it doesn't exist?

Comment: @SerjSagan Not sure what could cause this behavior. [writeFile](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_writefile_file_data_options_callback) with the default settings creates the file if it doesn't exist.

Answer (score 17):

You can also use [gulp-file](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-file):

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var file = require('gulp-file');

gulp.task('version', function () {
    var pkg = require('package.json')

    return gulp.src('src/**')
        .pipe(file('version', pkg.version))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('build/'))
});
```

or without using `gulp.src()`:

```
gulp.task('version', function () {
    var pkg = require('package.json')

    return file('version', pkg.version, {src: true})
        .pipe(gulp.dest('build/'))
});
```

Answer (score 5):

The [gulp-header](https://github.com/godaddy/gulp-header) package can be used to prefix files with header banners.

eg. This will inject a banner into the header of your javascript files.

```
var header = require('gulp-header');
var pkg = require('./package.json');
var banner = ['/**',
  ' * <%= pkg.name %> - <%= pkg.description %>',
  ' * @version v<%= pkg.version %>',
  ' * @link <%= pkg.homepage %>',
  ' * @license <%= pkg.license %>',
  ' */',
  ''].join('\n');

gulp.src('./foo/*.js')
  .pipe(header(banner, { pkg: pkg } ))
  .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist/')
```

Gulp is a streaming build system leveraging pipes.

If you simply want to write a new file with an arbitrary string, you can use built in [node fs](http://nodejs.org/api/fs.html) object.

Answer (score 3):

Using the [string-to-stream](https://www.npmjs.com/package/string-to-stream) and [vinyl-source-stream](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vinyl-source-stream) modules:

```
var str = require('string-to-stream');
var source = require('vinyl-source-stream');
var gulp = require('gulp');

str('1.4.27').pipe(source('version.txt')).pipe(gulp.dest('dist'));
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's an answer that works in 2019.

**Plugin:**

```
var Vinyl = require('vinyl');
var through = require('through2');
var path = require('path');

// https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/tree/master/docs/writing-a-plugin#modifying-file-content
function stringSrc(filename, string) {
    /**
     * @this {Transform}
     */
    var transform = function(file, encoding, callback) {
        if (path.basename(file.relative) === 'package.json') {
            file.contents = Buffer.from(
                JSON.stringify({
                    name: 'modified-package',
                    version: '1.0.0',
                }),
            );
        }

        // if you want to create multiple files, use this.push and provide empty callback() call instead
        // this.push(file);
        // callback();

        callback(null, file);
    };

    return through.obj(transform);
}
```

And in your gulp pipeline:

```
gulp.src([
    ...
])
.pipe(stringSrc('version.json', '123'))
.pipe(gulp.dest(destinationPath))
```

From source: https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/tree/master/docs/writing-a-plugin#modifying-file-content

> The function parameter that you pass to through.obj() is a _transform
>   function which will operate on the input file. You may also provide an
>   optional _flush function if you need to emit a bit more data at the
>   end of the stream.
>
> From within your transform function call this.push(file) 0 or more
>   times to pass along transformed/cloned files. You don't need to call
>   this.push(file) if you provide all output to the callback() function.
>
> Call the callback function only when the current file (stream/buffer)
>   is completely consumed. If an error is encountered, pass it as the
>   first argument to the callback, otherwise set it to null. If you have
>   passed all output data to this.push() you can omit the second argument
>   to the callback.
>
> Generally, a gulp plugin would update file.contents and then choose to
>   either:
>
> call callback(null, file) or make one call to this.push(file)

Answer (score 1):

This can also be achieved using [gulp-tap](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-tap)

This can be especially helpful if you have identified multiple files that require this header. Here is relevant code (Also from gulp-tap documentation)

```
var gulp = require('gulp'),
    tap = require('gulp-tap');

gulp.src("src/**")
    .pipe(tap(function(file){
           file.contents = Buffer.concat([
             new Buffer('Some Version Header', 'utf8'),
             file.contents
           ]);
         }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dist');
```